# Shifting a 7seg display on NEXYS 4 DDR

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I have made a communication between a keyboard USB HID and Nexys 4 ddr. I have succeeded to output the letters I push(by decoding them and recoding in the letters I want to output), however I want to take it a step further and make the display so that when I push two letter I have the output"000000AB", for another letter pushed is "00000ABC" and so on.

I have tried to implement this idea by using a vector that I shift when my flag(the end bit from the data transmission) is 1(meaning a transmission ended) and coding the anode. However, my output is still the same, the whole segment displays the same letter.

My ps2receiver.

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity PS2Receiver is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           kclk : in STD_LOGIC;
           kdata : in STD_LOGIC;
           outData : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           flg: out std_logic);
end PS2Receiver;

architecture Behavioral of PS2Receiver is
signal kclkf: std_logic;
signal kdataf: std_logic;
signal datacur: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal dataprev: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal cnt: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0):="0000"; 
signal keycode: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):= (Others => '0');
signal flag: std_logic:='0';

component debouncer is
port(CLK: in std_logic;
     I0: in std_logic;
     I1: in std_logic;
    O0: out std_logic;
    O1:out std_logic );
end component;

begin

Deb: debouncer port map(clk=>clk,I0=>kclk,I1=>kdata,O0=>kclkf,O1=>kdataf);

--process(clk)
--begin 
--    if falling_edge(kclkf) then
--        case cnt is 
--              when "0000" => null ; --do nothing is the starting bit--0
--              when "0001" => datacur<="0000000" & kdataf;--1
--              when "0010" => datacur<="000000" & kdataf &"0";--2
--              when "0011" => datacur<="00000" & kdataf & "00";--3
--              when "0100" => datacur<="0000" & kdataf & "000";--4
--              when "0101" => datacur<="000" & kdataf & "0000";--5
--              when "0110" => datacur<="00" & kdataf & "00000";--6
--              when "0111" => datacur<="0" & kdataf & "000000";--7
---              when "1000" => datacur<= kdataf & "0000000";--8
--              when "1001" => flag<='1';--9
--              when "1010" => flag<='0';--10
--              when others=> NULL;
--        end case;-
--        if(cnt <= 9) then cnt<= cnt+1;
--        elsif cnt=10 then cnt<=(Others => '0');
--        end if;
--      end if; 
--end process;




process(clk)
begin 
    if falling_edge(kclkf) then
       case cnt is 
              when "0000" => null ; --do nothing is the starting bit--0
            when "0001" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 1) & kdataf;--1
         when "0010" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 2) & kdataf & datacur(0);--2
       when "0011" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 3) & kdataf & datacur(1 downto 0);--3
              when "0100" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 4) & kdataf & datacur(2 downto 0);--4
           when "0101" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 5) & kdataf & datacur(3 downto 0);---5
            when "0110" => datacur<=datacur(7 downto 6) & kdataf & datacur(4 downto 0);--6
             when "0111" => datacur<=datacur(7) & kdataf & datacur(5 downto 0);--7
            when "1000" => datacur<= kdataf & datacur(6 downto 0);--8
            when "1001" => flag<='1';--9
            when "1010" => flag<='0';--10
             when others=> NULL;
       end case;
       if(cnt <= 9) then cnt<= cnt+1;
        elsif cnt=10 then cnt<=(Others => '0');
      end if;
end if; 
end process;

process(flag)
begin 
    if rising_edge(flag) then 
        if NOT(dataprev = datacur) then 
           keycode(31 downto 24)<= keycode(23 downto 16);
           keycode(23 downto 16)<= keycode(15 downto 8);
           keycode(15 downto 8)<= dataprev;
           keycode(7 downto 0)<= datacur;
           dataprev<= datacur;           
            end if;
        end if;
end process;
flg<= flag;
outData<=keycode;


end Behavioral;
```

My main function

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;


entity top is
Port ( 
Clk: in std_logic;
Rst: in std_logic;
PS2_clk: in std_logic;
PS2_data: in std_logic;
SEG: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
AN: out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
DP: out std_logic;
UART_TXD: out std_logic
);
end top;

architecture Behavioral of top is
signal smallerCLK:std_logic:='0';
signal keycode: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
--signal PS2_clk:  std_logic;
--signal PS2_data:  std_logic;
component PS2RECEIVER is 
Port    ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           kclk : in STD_LOGIC;
           kdata : in STD_LOGIC;
           outData : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           flg: out std_logic);
end component;

component DCD is
 Port (
 input: in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
 CLK: in std_logic;
 output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
  );
end component DCD;
signal output:  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal flag: std_logic;
begin

process(clk)
begin
if(rising_edge(clk)) then smallerCLK<=NOT smallerCLK;
end if;
end process;


PS2: PS2RECEIVER port map (smallerCLK,PS2_CLK,PS2_DATA,keycode,flag);

--DC:DCD port map(keycode(7 downto 0),smallerCLK,output);
display: entity WORK.displ7seg
            port map(Clk => Clk,
                     Rst => Rst,
                     Data => keycode,
                     An => An,
                     Seg => Seg,
                     Dp=>Dp,
                     flag=> flag);

end Behavioral;
```

And the display:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;

entity displ7seg is
    Port ( Clk  : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Rst  : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Data : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);   -- datele pentru 8 cifre (cifra 1 din stanga: biti 31..28)
           An   : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);    -- selectia anodului activ
           Seg  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);   -- selectia catozilor (segmentelor) cifrei active
           Dp: out std_logic;
           flag: in std_logic);

end displ7seg;

architecture Behavioral of displ7seg is

constant CNT_100HZ : integer := 2**20;                  -- divizor pentru rata de reimprospatare de ~100 Hz (cu un ceas de 100 MHz)
signal Num         : integer range 0 to CNT_100HZ - 1 := 0;
signal NumV        : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (19 downto 0) := (others => '0');    
signal LedSel      : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal Hex         : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal AUX : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal anod : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal bufferBuffer: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):="00000000";
signal MUX : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0) := (others => '0');
signal REG1, REG2, REG3, REG4,REG5,REG6,REG7,REG8 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '1');
SIGNAL registerdisplay: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):=(others=>'1');
SIGNAL date: std_logic_vector(63 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
--signal vet: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);



begin
  Dp <='1'; 

-- Proces pentru divizarea ceasului
divclk: process (Clk)
    begin
    if (rising_edge(clk)) then
        if (Rst = '1') then
            Num <= 0;
        elsif (Num = CNT_100HZ - 1) then
            Num <= 0;
        else
            Num <= Num + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
    end process;


    NumV <= CONV_STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (Num, 20);
    LedSel <= NumV (19 downto 17);

-- Selectia anodului activ
   Anod <= "11111110" when LedSel = "000" else
        "11111101" when LedSel = "001" else
        "11111011" when LedSel = "010" else
        "11110111" when LedSel = "011" else
        "11101111" when LedSel = "100" else
         "11011111" when LedSel = "101" else
         "10111111" when LedSel = "110" else
         "01111111" when LedSel = "111" else
        "11111111";


-- Selectia cifrei active
    Hex <= Date (7  downto  0) when LedSel = "000" else
           Date (15  downto  8) when LedSel = "001" else
           Date (23 downto  16) when LedSel = "010" else
           Date (31 downto 24) when LedSel = "011" else
           Date (39 downto 32) when LedSel = "100" else
           Date (47 downto 40) when LedSel = "101" else
           Date (55 downto 48) when LedSel = "110" else
           Date (63 downto 56) when LedSel = "111" else
           "00000000";

-- Activarea/dezactivarea segmentelor cifrei active
process(clk)
begin
case HEX is 
        ----gfedcba----
         when "01000101"=> AUX <="11000000"; --0
         when "00010110"=> AUX <="11111001"; --1 
         when "00011110"=> AUX <="10100100"; --2
         when "00100110"=> AUX <="10110000"; --3
         when "00100101"=> AUX <="10011011"; --4
         when "00101110"=> AUX <="10010010"; --5
         when "00110110"=> AUX <="10000010"; --6
         when "00111101"=> AUX <="11111000"; --7
         when "00111110"=> AUX <="10000000"; --8
         when "01000110"=> AUX <="10010000"; --9  
         when "00011100"=> AUX <="10001000"; --A     
         when "00110010"=> AUX <="10000011"; --b    
         when "00100001"=> AUX <="11000110"; --C        
         when "00100011"=> AUX <="10100001"; --d
         when "00100100"=> AUX <="10000110"; --E
         when "00101011"=> AUX <="10001110"; --F 
         when "00110100"=> AUX <="10000010"; --G    
         when "00110011"=> AUX <="10001001"; --H     
         when "01000011"=> AUX <="11001111"; --I     
         when "00111011"=> AUX <="11110001"; --J
         when "01000010"=> AUX <="10001111"; --K    
         when "01001011"=> AUX <="11000111"; --L    
         when "00111010"=> AUX <="11001000"; --M
         when "00110001"=> AUX <="10101011"; --N
         when "01000100"=> AUX <="11000000"; --O    
         when "01001101"=> AUX <="10001100"; --P
         when "00010101"=> AUX <="10100001"; --Q    
         when "00101101"=> AUX <="10101111"; --r     
         when "00011011"=> AUX <="10010010"; --S
         when "00101100"=> AUX <="10000111"; --t
         when "00111100"=> AUX <="11000001"; --U
         when "00101010"=> AUX <="11010101"; --V                      
         when "00011101"=> AUX <="10011001"; --Y
         when "00011010"=> AUX <="10100100"; --Z
         when "00101001"=> AUX <="01110111"; -- Spaceend case
         when others=> NULL;
end case;
end process;

PROCESS(CLK)-
BEGIN
if(rising_edge(clk)) then

        if(flag=='1')then
           Date (63 downto 56)<=Date(55 downto 48);
            Date (55 downto 48) <= Date(47 downto 40);
             Date (47 downto 40)<=Date(39 downto 32);
            Date (39 downto 32)<= Date(31 downto 24);
           Date (31 downto 24)<= Date(23 downto 16);
            Date (23 downto  16) <=Date(15 downto 8);
            Date (15  downto  8) <= Date(7 downto 0);
           Date (7  downto  0) <=data(7 downto 0);
          end if;
end if;
END PROCESS;




AN<=aNOD;
Seg<= AUX;



end Behavioral;
```

As of right now it is :https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YBwU.jpg

I want to be able to see the keys I have pressed before and not have the same key all over my display.

Can somebody help me figure this out ?

Comment: I recall doing something similar... We multiplexed the outputs and inputs to the 7segments, and alternately displayed one number on one and the second number on the second. At however many Hz they run, half of it doesn't make all that much difference...

Comment: displ7seg has two syntax errors. ps2receiver is missing a library clause, there's a semantic error preventing simulation. The problem can't be duplicated without debouncer. The replicated F would be caused by `flag` being valid for more than one clock in the last process statement in displ7seg(Behavioral). You'll want flag = '1' for one clock, it's not produced by the same clock. You could separate the clock divider out or provide the count with a generic allowing debugging in simulation without millions of clock cycles while using a slower clock.